# $valid form property is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I've set up a form like so:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" name="regDev" ng-controller="regDevCtrl"  id="Register_dev" novalidate>

      <input ng-model="dev.name" type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" class="" required/>     

      <input ng-model="dev.email" type="email" name="email" value="" id="email"  class="" required/>        

      <input ng-model="dev.phone" type="tel" name="phone" value="" id="phone" class="" required/>      

      <input ng-model="dev.tos" type="checkbox" id="tos" name="tos" class="" required/>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_btn" class=""/>

        </form>
```

When trying to access `regDev.$valid` value I get `undefined` I can however use 
`regDev.checkValidity()` to check form validity and may access field properties like so:

`regDev.name.validity` logs:

```
ValidityState {valid: false, customError: false, badInput: false, stepMismatch: false, rangeOverflow: false…}
```

So I can access these values but I don't see documentation for this anywhere and it is far less convenient to use than the other suggested method.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with my code now. Did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to access

```
regDev.$valid
```

from a controller? If so, you should access it with:

```
$scope.regDev.$valid
```

If you are trying to access it from the HTML, like:

```
{{regDev.$valid}}
```

that *should* display the trutyness or falsyness of the variable.

You could also try:

```
regDev.text.$valid
```

That should give you the $valid value for that desired input field.

Comment: Sorry, But everything you I already tried much before asking here and  it is obviously not working .